# How to get the MilliSeconds between two Epoch time values using PIG script

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, epoch

### Game_ID |   BeginTime | EndTime

1  |   1235000140| 1235002457
 2  |   1235000377| 1235003300
 3  |   1235000414| 1235056128
 1  |   1235000414| 1235056128
 2  |   1235000377| 1235003300

**Here i would like to get the Milliseconds between two Epoch time fields, BeginTime and EndTime. Then Calculate the Average time for each games.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
games = load 'games.txt' using PigStorage('|') as (gameid: int, begin_time: long, end_time:long);

dump games; 
(1,1235000140,1235002457)
(2,1235000377,1235003300)
(3,1235000414,1235056128)
(1,1235000414,1235056128)
(2,1235000377,1235003300)
```

**Step 1:** Calculate the time difference

```
difference = foreach games generate gameid, end_time - begin_time as time_lapse;

dump difference;
(1,2317)
(2,2923)
(3,55714)
(1,55714)
(2,2923)
```

**Step 2:** Group the data on Game_ID

```
game_group = group difference by gameid;

dump game_group;
(1,{(1,55714),(1,2317)})
(2,{(2,2923),(2,2923)})
(3,{(3,55714)})
```

**Step 3:** Then the Average

```
average = foreach game_group generate group, AVG(difference.time_lapse);

dump average;
(1,29015.5)
(2,2923.0)
(3,55714.0)
```

Comment: Excellent Answer, so quick... much appreciate